# Find back-end data source for a website

Tags: json, google-chrome, web, web-scraping

I am trying to find the JSON endpoint for the stock chart on https://vip.btcchina.com/.

In Chrome, I tried "Inspect element" > "Network"

This showed me the JSON endpoints for some other data sources on the site, such as:

https://data.btcchina.com/data/ticker?market=all

https://data.btcchina.com/data/grouporder?market=cnyltc

I'm looking for a similar endpoint for their chart data, but it does not show up in the Network tab of Chrome. Any other ideas for how I could find it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at chart.js:

https://com.btcchinacdn.com/js/chart.js?v=234

It looks like the chart data is being pushed to the browser using WebSockets.

Comment: Interesting, good find! I've never worked with WebSockets. I imagine that I have to connect to some kind of URL, right? I'm not seeing one in this .js file.

Comment: You do, yes. The URL could be anywhere, hard to say.